# Unpacking error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    lstOfitems= list(leterCount.values())
    HstNumber = max(lstOfitems)
    ListOfkeys= list(leterCount.keys())
    NumberofChar = len(ListOfkeys)
    tess = turtle.Turtle()
    tess.color("white")
    tess.fillcolor("white")
    tess.pensize(3)
    wn = turtle.Screen()             
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.setworldcoordinates(0-BORDER,0-BORDER,FORWARD*NumberofChar+BORDER,HstNumber+BORDER)
    for a,b in(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys):
        drawBar(tess, a, b)
```

The above code takes in a string and counts how many charters there are and stores then in a dictionary. I'm trying to then make a bar chart after that but i run in to the problem where i get an error saying there are to vaules to unpack. How do i fix this ?

the trace back is this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\lab8excirse2.py", line 76, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\lab8excirse2.py", line 74, in main
    loopSTr()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\lab8excirse2.py", line 47, in loopSTr
    for a,b in(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I think you just need `zip(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys)`.

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys)` to `zip(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys)`. `(lstOfitems,ListOfkeys)` is simply a `tuple` consisting of two `list`s, you cannot unpack it. However, Python's built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) function will return an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables; which is what you want.

But a better way to do this is to access the dictionary keys/value pairs using the dictionary's 'items`method:`for b,a in leterCount.items():`

Having said that, are you aware that Python `collections` has a `dict` sub-class called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that does pretty much what you want? You can use it like so:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter('gallahad') # a new counter from an iterable
# c will then be: Counter({'a': 3, 'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'g': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want something like this:

```
 for b,a in leterCount.items():
    drawBar(tess, a, b)
```